# Script Error in Visual Studio 2008 Documentation

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Since several weeks, I have the following problem:
When I am accessing the Visual Studio 2008 Documentation, each page displays the error in German:

```
Skriptfehler

In dem Skript auf dieser Seite ist ein Fehler aufgetreten.
Zeile: 1
Zeichen: 1
Fehler: Syntaxfehler
Code: 0
URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=...

Möchten Sie, dass Skripts auf dieser Seite weiterhin ausgeführt werden?
Ja Nein
```

which is in English:

```
Script Error

An error occured in the script on this page.
Line: 1
Character: 1
Error: Syntax error
Code: 0
URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=...

Do you want that scripts will be executed on this page in future?
Yes No
```

This happens for each page of the documentation, and appearently, no matter if I click yes or no, the page is displayed correctly. But I have to click on one of teh buttons for each and every page of the help each time I access it.

My environment if that is important: Windows 7 SP1 64 bit German, Visual Studio 2008 English, IE8 German.

Answer (score 0):

Have found this advice from Microsoft, try it:

```
(1) go to Tools>Options>Web Browser,  
(2) change the conetents of Home
Page and point to ....http://msdn.microsoft.com, and  
(3) click the Ok button.   

Those messages are gone when I give it a try  in the Seach tab.
```

Comment: I tried that, closed IE, closed rthe MS help window, and selected a .net class name in VS2008 C# editor, hit F1, and the error message continues to show.

Answer (score 0):

Close Visual Studio incl. Help (MS Help Viewer), then go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\ (which is "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\" in my case) and rename the directory HelpViewer2.0 to HelpViewer2.0.old (just in case), then restart the IDE. Reconfigure Visual Studio Help Viewer for local use if you need to. That fixed it for me. Good luck!

Comment: VS2008 didn't even use Help Viewer 2.0 it used the previous Microsoft Document Explorer.